# Recreate image scales fails with 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: plone

How to prevent a 502 on recreating image scales on portal_atct/manage_imageScales?
It's necessary to do this after a layout change causing a change in dimension of one custom image scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are running Plone behind Apache, ngnix, varnish or similar proxying web server. The view just took longer to do it's work than the front-end time-out allowed, but the server will continue it's work in the background.

To prevent the 502 Bad Gateway error, access the server directly (port 8080, probably).